# Show there exists a differentiable function which is extension of $f: (0,\infty) \to\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = x^2\sin(1/x).$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Define $f: (0,\infty) \to\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = x^2\sin(1/x).$ Show that there is differentiable function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that extends $f.$

We can see that $\lim_{x\to0} x^2\sin(1/x) = 0$

Therefore $f(0)=0$

Further $f'(0) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{h^2\sin(1/h)-0}{h}= \lim_{h\to0} h\sin(1/h)=0$

Therefore $f'(0)=0$

Now I am unable to proceed.

Comment: What does $g$ have to do with $f$?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried? Can you figure out what the function $g$ should look like (in particular, what $g(0)$ should be)?

Comment: since for extended function g=f for every x where domain of g contains domain of f, since f(0)=0 so g(0) should also be 0.

Comment: Hint: Try to compute $\lim_{x\to0^+} f(x)$

Comment: f(0) is not yet 0 until you define it to be. Indeed, you can prove that this definition yields that f has a right-derivative.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\;\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}f(x)=0\;$ , the extension must fulfill $\;g(0)=0\;$ , and then

$$f'(0)_+=g'(0)_+=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x=\lim_{x\to0^+}x\sin\frac1x=0$$

So you need a differentiable function $\;g:(-\infty,0]\to\Bbb R\;$ s.t. the function

$$h:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R\,,\,\,h(x)=\begin{cases}f(x),&x>0\\{}\\g(x),&x\le0\end{cases}$$

is differentiable **and also** $\;g'(0)_-=0\;$ ...Well, can you think of such a function $\;g\;'$ ...?

Comment: what if $g(x)=x^2$ it is differentiable in $R$ and $g'(0)=0$.

Comment: @yogendrasingh That works...but there is an even easier option: $\;g(x)=0\;$ ...